# JPA orphanRemoval not working when cascading MERGE

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a three classes scenario. Classes `User` and `UserDetail` are associated by a `@OneToOne` relationship, while `UserDetail` and `Document` are associated by a `@OneToMany` relationship. I have used `CascadeType.ALL` and `orphanRemoval=true` on both of them, as described below.

As the classes specify, a User does not necessarilly have a UserDetail, but every UserDetail must have a User (therefore the `optional` flag). Every Document must be associated to a UserDetail. This is not an optional relationship!

```
public class User {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, optional = true, orphanRemoval = true)
    private UserDetail details;
}

public class UserDetail {
    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "detail", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Document> documents;
}

public class Document {
    @ManyToOne
    private UserDetail detail;
}
```

Everything works fine on persisting, whith all data being saved, but when I try to set UserDetail to `null` whith a document list is populated, I get an integrity constraint violation exception at the Documents. The foreign key to UserDetail can't be set to null.

As far as I could understand, when setting `details` to null on User object and trying to merge it, the provider tries to delete the orphan UserDetail, but does not cascade the delete command correctly. If I try do DELETE the User, then the cascading operation works perfectly and no exception gets thrown.

### Question:

#### Shouldn't merge operation trigger the deletion of everything, since I'm cascading and using `orphanRemoval`?

Obs.: Using (Hibernate 4.3.7) as provider

Comment: Can you provide sample code where you set the `UserDetail` to `null`?

Comment: Nothing fancy, really, just retrieve User, call something like `user.setDetails(null)` and merge.

Comment: Since it's an bi-directional association you should consider removing the user from the Details too, not just altering one side.

Comment: Did you found any solution to this @FelipeLeão? I'm having the same problem with Hibernate 5.3.1

Comment: Sorry @PeterCatalin, it was a long time ago, but I probably just went on some other direction.